# How to remove extra information from a URL

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I noticed that when I put a link in my LinkedIn updates LinkedIn feels the need to add '#!' to the end of the URL . That seems to be a problem when I try to show off a calendar my company has installed.

SO I figure I would just link to a PHP file and redirect from there to the calendar. But even after specifying an absolute URL in the code, the '#!' is still appended to the end of the end of the URL.

The code I was using for that redirect:

```
<?php
     $url = "http://calendar.example.com";
     header( 'location:'.$url ) ;
?>
```

Still sends me to http://calendar.exmpale.com/#!

How do I convince the code to remove that '#!' that is causing problems? Also, why does LinkedIn do this?

Comment: You will need to use `mod_rewrite` to get rid of it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with LinkedIn but are you able to provide a URL without creating an `<a href="">` tag? Maybe just post the URL as straight text so that the user has to copy+paste? The `#!` sounds like a security feature that doesn't allow users to blindly click links.

Comment: On a side note, I am confused as to why it breaks your redirect script? Going to http://www.yahoo.com/#! doesn't cause theirs to break and my personal site handles it OK.

Comment: The software uses information in the URL to identify which event on the calendar to show.

calendar.example.com/#!event_2013_9_4_1_9_1_Some+Event

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are only client side you can not use `mod_rewrite` to remove it as mentioned above.  I would use javascript.

```
window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
```

Comment: As far as hashes go, I know for a fact that when trying to share a link that contains an anchor (aka hashtag), Facebook will strip it out, that's why I thought it would be the same situation for the OP and LinkedIn.